# Hide play button on Safari Mobile - iOS 7

Tags: ios7, html5-video, mobile-safari, video.js

I'm using video.js with a custom skin for some videos on an html page.
Everything is working fine except for Safari Mobile iOS 7, cause it doesn't hide the default play button for videos.
I'm using all this css rules

```
.video-js video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display:none !important;
}
.video-js video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.video-js video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.video-js video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none!important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

and actually i can see these rules on inspector but they are simply not working.
Is there a way to hide the button or is that a safari bug?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: this answer works for controls panel play button and not for big play button over video element

1. There are different CSS styles for shadow elements on different iOS versions.

For iOS 7 instead of

`.video-js video::--webkit-media-controls-play-button`

should be

`.video-js video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button`

2. Here is a list of all shadow subelements in HTML **video** element on iOS 7 (I've checked it on my devices):

`<div>`:

- video::-webkit-media-controls
- video::-webkit-media-controls-panel
- video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline-container
- video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display
- video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display
- video::-webkit-media-controls-panel

`<input type="button">`:

- video::-webkit-media-controls-rewind-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-return-to-realtime-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-back-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-seek-forward-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider-mute-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-min-button
- video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-max-button

`<input type="range">`:

- video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline
- video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider
- video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-volume-slider

Comment: Is there anything the works on the big play button over the <video> element?

Comment: @Keab42 Unfortunately, no